# Reflection not working in ios in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am using the below code in my application and it is working fine in android, and even on iphone simulator as well but not working on real iPhone device. I would be immensely grateful if anyone could help me.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.logic.form.ClassName");
Screen screen = (Screen) clazz.newInstance();
screen.show(parameter);
```

Comment: Cn1 does not support Reflection

Comment: That is true.  But Class.forName() and Class.newInstance() should still work.

Comment: If you can access your device log (e.g. hook it up to a mac via USB), it will show a stack trace which will tell you want the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that. While it "might" work it will probably have serious problems e.g. on Android where we obfuscate class names and on iOS where a class will be stripped if it's unused.

There is no valid reason to use `Class.forName()` in Codename One as mobile device don't allow dynamic class downloading or classpath magic.. You can use class literals to get dynamic code, these will work on all OS's e.g.:

```
Class clazz = com.logic.form.ClassName.class;
```